# filename~ipad.xib naming convention

Tags: iphone, xib, nib, universal

The issue I am having with this naming convention ~iPad.xib is that everything loads properly in the iPad simulator. Although when I build the project on the device only the iPhone Views load. This has been driving me crazy. Please if anyone knows why this is doing this it would be much appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Did you try `~ipad` (lowercase)?  The simulator is lenient when it comes to capitalization.

Comment: I'll post it as an answer then so others can see it's solved. Just mark it as answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Make sure you use `~ipad` (lowercase) instead of `iPad`. The simulator (and the underlying Mac OS X) is case-insensitive when it comes to capitalization, while the device is case-sensitive.

Comment: Are you sure that this behaviour is because of the simulator as opposed to the underlying filesystem type? A default Mac OS X installation formats the file system as case-insensitive, case-preserving.

Comment: @Bavarious: I hadn't really thought about that.  That could be a possibility.  I'll edit the question.